# Crystal Reports - adding DefaultAnimation.gif to resources (Visual Studio 2015)

Tags: visual-studio-2015, .net-4.0, crystal-reports-2010

I am working on a project that uses Crystal Reports and the CR had to finally get updated from 2005 to 2010. And that of course had to cause some problems. Most of them I managed to solve, but one gives me sleepless nights already:

> Additional information: Resource „DefaultAnimation.gif” cannot be found in class „MyFramework.Core.Application.ctrSysCrystalReport”.

The class ctrSysCrystalReport obviously inherits the CrystalReportViewer:

```
Public Class ctrSysCrystalReport
    Inherits CrystalDecisions.Windows.Forms.CrystalReportViewer
```

And of course I tried adding a file of that name both to class's and project's resources (.resx), setting its Build Action to "Embedded", naming it both "DefaultAnimation" and "DefaultAnimation.gif", and... got nowhere.

I tried searching all over the internet, but it's virtually the only projected solution. And as far as I remember this worked for me in another project, but in VS 2010 it's dead end (and that wouldn't be the first time when VS2015 and Roslyn caused a lot of confusion).

Any idea what to do with this?

Or maybe it's possible to add resources to a class in runtime? I know how that sounds, but I'm so lost with it I'm thinking of any solution, and the added image is of course visible in the project's recoures

```
My.Resources.DefaultAnimation
```

but from what I've figured out the CR's code looks something like:

```
Me.progressAnimationImage = New Bitmap(MyBase.GetType(), "DefaultAnimation.gif")
```

so maybe it could work if I managed to add a resource to a class instead of the whole assembly?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, so the answer is - always be sure you have the latest version. Update 13.0.20 solves this issue.